# Histogram bar width

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am using matplotlib histogram histtype='bar' to plot four datasets together. What it automatically does is that it changes the width of the bar of each dataset relative to the size of the dataset. I want to have equal bar width for all four datasets.

```
[n, bins, patches = plt.hist(
    [np.sort(x2), np.sort(x3), np.sort(x4), np.sort(x5)],
    bins=np.logspace(np.log10(8e-8), np.log10(1), 7),
    histtype='bar', 
    weights=[w2,w3,w4,w5],
    label=[
        '$\Delta {{\chi}^2} <40$',
        '$u_0 < 0.045$',
        '${s}_{fitted} >5$',
        'Multi-peaked'
    ]
)][1]
```

[image: My current plot]

Comment: No, you set the bar width yourself via the `bins` argument.

Comment: Thanks, but I’m not sure if I understand your point. My understanding is that the bins are the same for all datasets, so how does that determine the widths?

Comment: @somayehkhakpash are you sure you want a histogram and not a [bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/barchart_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-barchart-demo-py)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, this kind of plot is really misleading. You kind of want a categorical histogram? I think you might decide to calculate the histogram first, then plot a barplot with the bars at the positions and widths you want.

Comment: @somayehkhakpash Try passing the argument `rwidth` to `plt.hist()` with an integer value like `1`, `2, etc.

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón I want a histogram, but I guess I can use the histogram to do a bar plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I guess that would work. I will try it if  don't find any other ways to fix my histogram.

Comment: @ammar I tried that, but rwidth determines the width of the bars relative to the bin size. It doesn't change the width of individual bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bins are actually the same size (numeric value) for each set but your x axis is logarithmic so it looks like the *width* is different. Try to plot a single dataset in a linear x axis (not logarithmic) and you will see that the widths of the bars are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. Do you suggest a way to fix that? Because I need to keep the x axis in log scale.

Comment: The only way to keep x axis in log scale and show same width is to have different bin sizes with a logarithmin relation between then. Then they will be shown linearly (same width) in the x axis logarithim plot.